# React-Router-Dom v6.-fetching images from Cloudinary (State update on an unmounted component console error)

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-router-dom, cloudinary

I am trying to fetch images from Cloudinary that I uploaded using NodeJs to create a React gallery app. I was able to get the backend working properly and my images are uploading to Cloudinary. However, with the react-router-dom update to v6, I have been unable to successfully fetch the images from Cloudinary so that they automatically get added to the gallery section of the app. This might be because I am trying to update the code that was built with v5 to the latest version of react-router-dom v6.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong and how I can fix this issue is greatly appreciated. The console error says...

"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'cloudinary-react';

export default function Home() {
const [imageIds, setImageIds] = useState();
const loadImages = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('/api/images');
        const data = await res.json();
        setImageIds(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

 useEffect(() => {
    loadImages();
 }, []);

 return (
    <div>
        <h1 className="title">Cloudinary Gallery</h1>
        <div className="gallery">
            {imageIds &&
                imageIds.map((imageId, index) => (
                    <Image
                        key={index}
                        cloudName= 
                        {process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_NAME}
                        publicId={imageId}
                        width="300"
                        height="200"
                        crop="scale"
                    />
                ))}
        </div>
    </div>
   );


This is an image of the error in my console
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03zmt.jpg
```

Comment: Is the Home component return a JSX element?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just added the code that I am using to this question